# Probabilty and Continous Models

Tags: probability

I am reading a probability books and while reading continuous models it states that:

> It makes sense to assign probability 'b' to 'a' to any subinterval [b-a] of [0-1], and to calculate probability of a more complicated set by evaluating its length.
>
> The “length” of a subset S of [0,1] is the integral ∫S dt,which is defined, for “nice” sets S, in the usual calculus sense.  For unusual sets, this integral may not be well defined mathematically, but such issues belong to a more advanced treatment of the subject. Incidentally, the legitimacy of using length as a probability law hinges on the fact that the unit interval has an uncountably infinite number of elements. Indeed, if the unit interval had a countable number of elements, with each element having zero probability, the additivity axiom would imply that the whole interval has zero probability, which would contradict the normalization axiom.

My questions are:

1. What actually a "length" of a subset mean here?
2. How length and integral are related here. I am unable to map the connection.
3. What does it mean to a "nice" set?
4. I cannot understand the last logical explanation where he tries to prove integration a legitimate solution to probability by giving contradiction example. I will be needing a simple explanation here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Lenght means measure. It can mean lenght, volume, area. And a lot more. Nice means measurable. You can find more about it in a book about measure theory

Comment: any suggestions on measure theory book?

Comment: You'd do better to ask your teacher, but i can recommend some of Rudins analysis books

Answer (score 1):

Integrals are a way to measure sets. Indeed, for a set $S$, let $\chi_S$ denote the indicator function of $S$. Notice that $b-a=\int_a^b dt=\int_0^1\chi_{[a,b]}(t)dt$, so the length of an interval is the same as the integral of the indicator function of said interval. We can try to define the size (or length) of a general set in this way, namely, the size of a set $S$ is $\int_0^1\chi_S(t)dt$. Of course, this doesn't work for all sets since $\chi_S$ may not be integrable. For instance, if we are using Riemann integrals, $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}$ is not integrable. For the more general Lebesgue measure, there are other sets for which this integral is undefined. Being a ``nice set'' means integrable. Of course, in reality a measure of size must be defined in order to talk about an integral to start with, so we're looking at this backward. Regardless, hopefully this can help you understand where they're coming from. I recommend finding a book on measure theory to learn more

Comment: can you recommend some?

Comment: Rudin's analysis book is good. Also, if you want an introduction to measure motivated by probability, I like Williams' Probability with Martingales